# Showing only one variable in R barplot

Tags: r

I have two binary variables consisting of 0 and 1 value. I want to create a barplot of the two variable that only shows the count of value equal to 1. I created the following code:

```
counts = table(Flag1, Flag2)  
barplot(counts, beside = TRUE)
```

this code gives me the following plot:
[image]

I am trying to create a plot similar to this one but that only shows the two barplots for the value 1 instead of both 0 and 1 barplots. Is there any way to achieve this in R?

Any suggestions or tips would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can subset `counts` before sending to `barplot`.

```
counts <- as.matrix(table(mtcars$vs, mtcars$am)[, 2])
```

Note I've used `as.matrix` because it would drop to a vector without and that is what controls the standard palette.

```
barplot(counts, beside = TRUE)
```

[image]

Comment: `barplot(counts[,2,drop=FALSE],beside=TRUE)` also avoids the `as.matrix`